# How to typecast keccak256 function with multiple arguments to uint256?

Tags: solidity, keccak, type-casting

solidity ^0.4.19 (works)

```
uint256 randNonce++;
return uint256(keccak256(msg.sender, randNonce, now))
```

solidity ^0.4.24 (throws)

```
uint256 randNonce++;
return uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, randNonce, now)));
```

throws:
`Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible your function `returns(uint8)` ?

This compiles:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract HashToUint {

    uint256 randNonce;

    function test() public returns(uint) {
        randNonce++;
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, randNonce, now)));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Solved the issues! embarrassing ;)